# Transactional Control from an EJB

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I'm fairly new to JavaEE/JPA and I've encontered the following need in my project, a need that I've searched for a while how to achieve, but without success so far, so I was hoping any of you could point my mistake and hopefully, also tell me how the correct solution works, for me to learn instead of just copying a piece of working code.

Problem:

Inside my Bean, I have a method the calls 3 diferent JPA persistent methods(1 persist and 2 merges), but I have to ensure that, if one or more of these persistent methods fails, I can rollback the whole transaction, to avoid further problems.

That's a scratch of what my bean looks like:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "FuncionarioBean")
@Remote(FuncionarioBeanRemote.class)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)//Was instructed to put this annotation, but I don't know the real impact of it in my application if it was set as a CONTAINER.
public class FuncionarioBean implements FuncionarioBeanRemote {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx;

    @Override
    public void updateFuncionario(FuncionarioEntity funcionarioEditado) {

        try{
            utx.begin();
            /* irrelevant code */
            callJPAMergeMethod1();
            /* irrelevant code */
            callJPAMergeMethod2();
            /* irrelevant code */
            callJPACreateMethod1();
            /* irrelevant code */
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            utx.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm setting one of the elements to be updated/merged to null(column is NOT NULL) to ensure there will be exceptions, but for some unknown reasons(at least for me), no exceptions are thrown and the other methods keep being executed. If I delete the UserTransaction methods and remove the `@TransationManagement` annotation, an exception will be thrown, but I'll have no way to rollback the whole method.

Can any of you tell me what I'm doing wrong in here?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Best Regards,

Enrico Bergamo.

Answer (score 0):

`@TransactionManagement` is not needed for this purpose.

The container will rollback when a:

- system exception
- (un)checked exception annotated with @ApplicationException

is thrown provided that your EE-container is capable. 
Since e.g. NullPointerException is an unchecked exception non system exception the rollback isn't usualy provided here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use neither the `UserTransaction`, nor the `@TransactionManagement` annotation, nor to throw any exceptions.

The behaviour as you describe it is **the default JPA behaviour**. If one or more of the operations fail on transaction commit, the whole transaction - meaning all operations performed in the transaction on the database - will be rolled back. The rollback is performed automatically by the JPA provider, so you don't have to do anything "manually".

There is however one thing you should be aware of - if you are managing JPA relations in the method - i.e. nulling references and such, you would need to either restore them or reload the entities on transaction rollback.